# iam unable to create new DB in pgadmin4

Tags: pgadmin-4

is there a way to resolve it or any alternative option..?[in this image u can view there's no create DB option](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Y6FLI.png)

Comment: I've found the way, I just needed to make the user a super user

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Which is the user you logged in ?

Try to log in with a user that has priviledges to create new databases.

There are 10 Login/group roles in the image you've posted,
find the one with that priviledges, and log in using that user.